# Верно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Оба они вместе пережили осаду, и обоим странно было наконец-то оказаться внутри этих стен, в замке, который так долго сопротивлялся объединенной дарийской армии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Оба они вместе пережили осаду, и обоим странно было наконец-то оказаться внутри этих стен, **в замке, который так долго сопротивлялся объединенной дарийской армии.***

Постановка тире не является обязательной, это факультативное решение. Тире обозначает **увеличенную паузу и присоединительный характер** конструкции, но в данном случае особой необходимости в этом нет.

Comment: Тире при пояснении не обозначает увеличенную паузу, причем никогда. Пояснение с запятыми внутри, обособляемое запятыми, если и можно найти, то это будет что-то очень редкое, так как серия запятых затрудняет понимание того, что к чему относится.

Comment: Здесь "в замке" обособленное запятой пояснение, после которого следует придаточное определительное предложение.  В вашем варианте  присоединительная конструкция "в замке, который так долго сопротивлялся объединенной дарийской армии", обособленная тире. Оба варианта возможны, но автор имеет право на выбор.

Comment: Это не присоединительная конструкция, а пояснительная. Определительное предложение, которое относится к слову в пояснении, является частью пояснения, а не предложения, к сочетанию или слову которого дается пояснение, — это очевидно, если пояснение находится в середине предложения. Можно изменить предложение для наглядности: ‟Внутри этих стен — в замке, который так долго сопротивлялся объединенной дарийской армии, — они вместе пережили осаду”.

Comment: Присоединительная конструкция – это общий термин для синтаксических конструкций разного вида.  При отсутствии союзных средств  для обособления используется тире.. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120  пункты 6, 7.

Comment: ‟Присоединительная конструкция – это общий термин для синтаксических конструкций разного вида” — под это определение подходит любая синтаксическая конструкция. Уточнение — ограничение предшествующего тремина. Пояснение — отступление с целью внесения дополнительной информации о слове или сочетании. Присоединение — прибавочная информация, которой автор решает дополнить завершенное предложение. Предложения в пунктах 6 и 7(в пункте 6 вообще нет ни одного тире) не имеют ничего общего с предложением в вопросе. Например: ‟Видел я на днях «Крокодиловы слёзы» — бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда (Ч.);”

Comment: ‟Бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда” — это отношение автора к чему-то, что действительно является присоединением. Вот второе предложение: ‟Руки у него огромные-преогромные — просто ужас”. ‟Просто ужас” — также выражение отношения автора. Как эти предложения связанны с обсуждаемой темой? Зачем вы дали мне ссылку на это? В предложении в вопросе пояснение ‟в замке, который” поясняет сочетание ‟эти стены”. Вот тогда ссылка на главу про пояснительные конструкции: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119#pp119. Возможно, вы просто из-за рассеянности не заметили эту главу.

Comment: И почему если появляется тире, то это становится присоединением, а не пояснением, если 80 процентов примеров про пояснение в соответствующей главе пишутся с тире? За что я не люблю этот форум, так это за то, что приходится тратить время и отвечать на какие-то совершенно идиотские комментарии.

Comment: Jim Korbett, вы мне, право, нравитесь. Я вот тоже не очень люблю отвечать на комментарии, но решила, что не ответить совсем будет невежливо. Но в то же время надеялась, что одного комментария будет вполне достаточно. Обменялись мнениями – и прекрасно!  Зачем надо что-то доказывать. Поэтому в дальнейшем обещаю вам не больше одного комментария, ага?

Answer (score -1):

Нет, не правильно. Пояснение, имеющее внутри себя знаки препинания, обособляется тире, а не запятой. Правильно так: ‟Оба они вместе пережили осаду, и обоим странно было наконец-то оказаться внутри этих стен — в замке, который так долго сопротивлялся объединенной дарийской армии.”